# why t.join cannot be called twice in this example?

Tags: c++, stdthread

For some time I have been trying to use `std::thread`, and in my project i wanted to make sure that the threads are not making one thing couple times at once, that's why i am trying to make a simple project that has something like "check" if thread is done, and then start again

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void Thing() 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
}
int main() 
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task(Thing);
    auto future = task.get_future();

    std::thread t(std::move(task));

    while (true) {
        auto status = future.wait_for(0ms);

        if (status != std::future_status::ready) 
        {
            std::cout << "not yet" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            t.join();
            std::cout << "Join()" << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(300ms);
    }
}
```

using this code i have error at line with `std::cout << "Join()" << std::endl;` and the error says: `Unhandled exception at 0x7632A842 in dasd.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location 0x00AFF8D4.`
this error is comes out when the thread is ready, and `t.join()` is called.

output of this project:

```
not yet

...

not yet
Join()
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: _why t.join cannot be called twice in this example?_ If a thread has been joined it's not joinable anymore. A 2nd join is not allowed.

Comment: A second join makes no sense at all. A task can only end once so what should happen if we can call two times join? Even if it will not throw an exception, what should happen? The task was ended before and the join action was done. What a second join can do in such a situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

`join` has as post condition

> joinable() is false

and in error condition

> invalid_argument if joinable() is false

So you cannot call it twice as you do.

You probably want to break the loop once you call `join` or rewrite your loop such as:

```
while (future.wait_for(300ms) != std::future_status::ready) {
    std::cout << "not yet" << std::endl;
}
t.join();
std::cout << "Join()" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need a `while` loop there. Instead, you could simply call `join`.

What `join` does is to wait for the thread to finish its job. After the thread finishes its job, it exits and cleans the stack and the second call to `join` doesn't make sense at all.

I also would suggest using [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) in case you want an async function that also returns a value.

Comment: While loop allows to print "progress".